# how can I find count of lanes in a road on veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

For my simulation I want to find out the count of lines in a single road. I search sumo and viens and there is nothing there. I can retrieves all lanes count in map but what about lanes(lines) in a single road?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply parse the sumo network. It is a quite straightforward XML file. For your specific question there is even support in the sumolib which is a python library coming with sumo.

```
net = sumolib.net.readNet("netfile")
edge = net.getEdge("edgeID")
numLanes = edge.getLaneNumber()
```

You can also look here: http://sumo.dlr.de/wiki/Tools/Sumolib